# Android splash screen for UNO UWP project

Tags: android, xamarin, splash-screen, uno-platform

I am trying to implement an splash screen for the Android part of my UNO solution. I can get the splash screen to appear, wait a few seconds but upon navigation to the main page I get the following exception in the app.cs

> ```
> protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
> {
> #if DEBUG
>     if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
>     {
>        // this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
>     }
>  #endif
>     Frame rootFrame = Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Content as Frame;
>
>     // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
>     // just ensure that the window is active
>     if (rootFrame == null)
>     {
>       // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
>            rootFrame = new Frame(); <<<<< exception
> ```

*Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference occurred*

The stack trace is as simple as :

> 0x25 in Uno1.App.OnLaunched at C:\Users\pjsta\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Uno1\Uno1\Uno1.Shared\App.xaml.cs:55,17 C#

The relevant part of the solution are 
1. my new SplashActivity in the Android project

```
 [Activity(Label = "SplashScreen", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.SplashActivity")]

   public class SplashActivity : Activity
   {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); 
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
             StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
```

2. Modification to MainActivity to not be the MainLauncher

   [Activity(
   MainLauncher = false, 
   ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation |
   ConfigChanges.ScreenSize,
   WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan | SoftInput.StateHidden )]

   public class MainActivity : Windows.UI.Xaml.ApplicationActivity
   {
   }

The relevant style loads fo the splash screen OK. Switching the MainActivity back to MainLauncher=true works , albeit without a splash screen.
I am a newbie to Xamarin and Android development, but competent in UWP. Anyone out there got any ideas?

Comment: First of all, calling `sleep()` on the main (UI) thread of an `Android` application will get you an ANR (Application Not Responding) crash. You absolutely positively cannot stall the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Second, in what method are you calling `new Frame()` where it crashes? Please post a stack trace. Your `Context` isn't properly initialized and that is what is causing the NPE.

Comment: Thanks for the input Dave, I have embellished my post with the info requested.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of Xamarin is not good. I can't help here. I've added the Xamarin tag to your question, hopefully someone who knows Xamarin will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception, it sounds like when `new Frame()` is called, the base native constructor is called with a null Context. This is probably because Uno expects `ApplicationActivity` to be run as MainLauncher=true. It's possible that inheriting your `SplashActivity` class from `Uno.UI.BaseActivity` could resolve the error.

A better way to show a splash screen on Android is to modify the theme rather than create a separate activity. I'll use the [Uno Gallery app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nventive.uno.ui.demo) as an [example](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.Playground).

1. Create a file in the Resources/drawable folder of your Android head called, eg, [splash.xml](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.Playground/blob/master/src/Uno.Playground.Droid/Resources/drawable/splash.xml). Define your splash screen visual appearance here.
2. Open the [Resources/values/Styles.xml](https://github.com/nventive/Uno.Playground/blob/master/src/Uno.Playground.Droid/Resources/values/Styles.xml) file. Inside the 'AppTheme' style add the following line:

   ```
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
   ```

Hope that helps. Also, please tag questions about the [Uno Platform](https://platform.uno/) as 'uno-platform' (the 'uno' tag refers to the OpenOffice component model).

Comment: Thanks, both these approaches worked, and just as importantly I have a reference sample for future issues